# How to debugg kernel panics?

Tags: hardware, debug

I have an Raspberry Pi V3 running as a home server for some years. Since a while ago, it doesn't run stable anymore, instead, after it is up for a couple of days sometime after a couple of hours, it gives me kernel panics. My first guess was a corrupted SD, so a changed it. My second guess was corrupted RAM, so I checked it with `memtest`:

```
memtester 1000 10
```

but everything seems to be ok.

My third guess was a faulty power adapter, so I tried with two other (originally branded Raspberry PI adapters) known as functional from other use cases. But nothing did help…

Knowing that every part of my hardware could be the cause, if corrupted, and not being able to make sense from the kernel messages I get, I would like to ask, whether or not it is possible to determine which part of the PI or it's peripherals is causing my pain.

Here is an excerpt of the messages, form the point they start:

```
[64538.754518] Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address 000048cc                                                                                            │
│[64538.761990] pgd = 9b71003a                                                                                                                                                │
│[64538.764970] [000048cc] *pgd=00000000                                                                                                                                      │
│[64538.768608] Internal error: Oops: 5 [#2] SMP ARM                                                                                                                          │
│[64538.773253] Modules linked in:                                                                                                                                            │
│[64538.776363] CPU: 0 PID: 28450 Comm: apache2 Tainted: G      D           4.19.66-v7+ #1253                                                                                 │
│[64538.784566] Hardware name: BCM2835                                                                                                                                        │
│[64538.788030] PC is at __radix_tree_lookup+0x10/0xb4                                                                                                                        │
│[64538.792871] LR is at radix_tree_lookup_slot+0x2c/0x50                                                                                                                     │
│[64538.797963] pc : [<80821898>]    lr : [<80821968>]    psr: a0000113                                                                                                       │
│[64538.804269] sp : ae8f1d08  ip : ae8f1d28  fp : ae8f1d24                                                                                                                   │
│[64538.809545] r10: 00000000  r9 : 0030a84e  r8 : 80d056ec                                                                                                                   │
│[64538.814812] r7 : 0030a84e  r6 : 000048c4  r5 : 00000040  r4 : 80d04d48                                                                                                    │
│[64538.821382] r3 : ae8f1d28  r2 : 00000000  r1 : 0030a84e  r0 : 000048c4                                                                                                    │
│[64538.827945] Flags: NzCv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment user                                                                                             │
│[64538.835127] Control: 10c5387d  Table: 12d2c06a  DAC: 00000055                                                                                                             │
│[64538.840922] Process apache2 (pid: 28450, stack limit = 0xc31374ad)                                                                                                        │
│[64538.847140] Stack: (0xae8f1d08 to 0xae8f2000)                                                                                                                             │
│[64538.851526] 1d00:                   80d04d48 00000000 000048c4 0030a84e ae8f1d44 ae8f1d28                                                                                 │
│[64538.859727] 1d20: 80821968 80821894 80d03d00 107c960d 00000009 00000001 ae8f1d6c ae8f1d48                                                                                 │
│[64538.867929] 1d40: 80235e98 80821948 00000000 80d054f4 80d04d48 00000000 000048c0 80d056ec                                                                                 │
│[64538.876125] 1d60: ae8f1dac ae8f1d70 802360e8 80235e74 a1dd76ec 80d8ee51 ae8f1dbc 107c960d                                                                                 │
│[64538.884309] 1d80: 80275070 80d054f4 ae9309c0 71fd8000 ae9309c0 00000040 aeb7b800 00000054                                                                                 │
│[64538.892488] 1da0: ae8f1dcc ae8f1db0 8028879c 8023609c ae8f1e34 3030a84e 80d04d48 ae9309c0                                                                                 │
│[64538.900665] 1dc0: ae8f1e1c ae8f1dd0 8027482c 80288758 ae8f1df4 80c92ad8 80275684 80d04d48                                                                                 │
│[64538.908842] 1de0: 00000054 a0000113 aeb7b800 107c960d ae8f1e1c ae9309c0 00000000 80d04d48                                                                                 │
│[64538.917018] 1e00: 00000054 00000040 aeb7b800 00000054 ae8f1e9c ae8f1e20 802757c8 802747b8                                                                                 │
│[64538.925195] 1e20: 00000000 ae8f1e30 80154fa8 8016c5a0 b9d5ad80 ae9309c0 00000054 006200ca                                                                                 │
│[64538.933371] 1e40: 00000000 71fd8000 92d2dc78 92d2dc78 18542760 00000000 00000000 00000000                                                                                 │
│[64538.941547] 1e60: 81113760 00000000 00000000 107c960d ae8f1e9c ae8f1fb0 ad78cb00 00000017                                                                                 │
│[64538.949724] 1e80: 71fd8230 ad505400 ad50543c 00000054 ae8f1ef4 ae8f1ea0 80836e28 80275348                                                                                 │
│[64538.957900] 1ea0: 80201c0c 80202e10 80c94e40 ad504800 b9d5ad00 ba352e40 ae8f1f0c 00000000                                                                                 │
│[64538.966086] 1ec0: 00000000 00000000 80144020 80d0a644 80d04d48 00000017 80836af8 71fd8230                                                                                 │
│[64538.974268] 1ee0: ae8f1fb0 00000000 ae8f1fac ae8f1ef8 8011665c 80836b04 ad78cb00 80d04d48                                                                                 │
│[64538.982446] 1f00: ae8f1f74 ae8f1f10 80830938 8014ad68 8027aad8 805159ac 000000e7 ad50543c                                                                                 │
│[64538.990623] 1f20: ae8f1f3c 80902408 396be000 80c94e40 80c949e8 80190794 80c949e8 00000000                                                                                 │
│[64538.998799] 1f40: ae8f1f5c ae8f1f50 80190794 801906b0 ae8f1f6c ae8f1f60 80126938 80190788                                                                                 │
│[64539.006975] 1f60: ae8f1f94 80101c9c 20000010 ffffffff 10c5387d 10c5387d 00000000 00000000                                                                                 │
│[64539.015151] 1f80: ae8f1fac 107c960d 76f76d24 20000010 ffffffff 10c5387d 10c5387d 00000000                                                                                 │
│[64539.023327] 1fa0: 00000000 ae8f1fb0 80101ca4 80116610 0000003a 000000c5 0000000b 020e267a                                                                                 │
│[64539.031504] 1fc0: 011b5d18 00000076 00000000 010a0930 00000087 00000000 00000000 76f9d970                                                                                 │
│[64539.039683] 1fe0: 71fd8148 7ebbf058 41c4cf59 76f76d24 20000010 ffffffff 00000000 00000000                                                                                 │
│[64539.047894] [<80821898>] (__radix_tree_lookup) from [<80821968>] (radix_tree_lookup_slot+0x2c/0x50)                                                                       │
│[64539.056981] [<80821968>] (radix_tree_lookup_slot) from [<80235e98>] (find_get_entry+0x30/0x110)                                                                           │
│[64539.065717] [<80235e98>] (find_get_entry) from [<802360e8>] (pagecache_get_page+0x58/0x348)
```

Comment: Try updating to a later kernel. 4.19.66-v7+ is a bit old now. Current development (rpi-update) kernel is 4.19.81-v7+

Comment: @Dougie Thanks for this advice. Unfortunately I can't do this easily, due to the fact, that my boot portion is considered to be too small: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=244917

Comment: Is the error always about the same? This one suggests a problem with the SD card or the bus, but it could also still be the memory. But since you can't change the bus, the CPU or the memory anyway, either of these cases would mean you need a new one...